# Stdin input to a command with nohup

Tags: io-redirection, nohup

from http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html

> nohup runs the given command with hangup signals ignored, so that the
>   command can continue running in the background after you log out.
>
> Synopsis: `nohup command [arg]...`
>
> If standard input is a terminal,
>   redirect it so that terminal sessions do not mistakenly consider the
>   terminal to be used by the command.

1. Why do we need to do this:

   > Make the substitute file
   >   descriptor unreadable, so that commands that mistakenly attempt to read from standard input can report an error.
2. Isn't redirection stdin from a file done by `nohup command [arg]... 0<myfile`? why `0>/dev/null`?

   > This redirection is a GNU extension; programs intended to be portable to non-GNU hosts can use `nohup command [arg]... 0>/dev/null` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are trying to run a complex script with nohup. You can detect if it tries to read stdin by redirecting stdin to a file descriptor that cannot be read from.  Look at these two examples: first `0</dev/null`:

```
rm nohup.out
nohup sh -c 'head -1' 0</dev/null
echo $?
cat nohup.out
```

The nohup.out file is empty, and the return code (`$?`) from the script is 0 ie ok, as the script just read end-of-file.  Now try the same script with `0>/dev/null` ie 0 opened for *output only*:

```
rm nohup.out
nohup sh -c 'head -1' 0>/dev/null
echo $?
cat nohup.out
```

This gives the error message in nohup.out of

```
head: error reading 'standard input': Bad file descriptor
```

and the exit code is 1, fail.  This is presumably more useful to you. You can also get the same effect by closing stdin with `0<&-`:

```
rm nohup.out
nohup sh -c 'head -1' 0<&-
echo $?
cat nohup.out
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't figure out if your reply answeres any of my two questions.

Comment: The redirection of stdin for nohup is entirely optional as nohup will usually redirect it to `</dev/null` if it was a terminal, to avoid the terminal not being able to close when you type exit. You can do your own `0<` redirection, to `/dev/null` or a file, to avoid this. If you don't expect your command to read stdin you can detect if it does by forcing such reads to return an error instead of end-of-file. You do this by opening stdin for writes only (`0>`) instead of the usual reads only (`0<`). It's still just optional, to help debug any problems, i.e. "good practice".

Comment: thanks. " This is presumably more useful to you." Do you mean exit code 1 is more useful than exit code 0?

Comment: Yes, it is easy in a shell script to test if a command failed with an exit other than zero (eg you can just do `if ! command; then ... fi`), and this is simpler than looking for error messages.